# ng-model depending of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML template that I want to use when the user is creating an item and also when is editing it.

I want to do something like this:

```
<input ng-model="newItem.description ? newItem.description : item.description"></input>
```

I know it can be done with this:

```
<input ng-if="newItem.description" ng-model="newItem.description"></input>
<input ng-if="item.description" ng-model="item.description"></input>
```

But, is there a way to do it using only one line?

Thanks!

Comment: why not simple `<input ng-model="item.description" />`?

Comment: @Grundy because I want to keep separate newItem and item

Comment: Mind if I ask what the context is?  Is this like for creating temporary changes and holding them before saving them?

Comment: can you provide a bit more code and markup? jsfiddle?

Comment: Try <input ng-model="newItem.description || item.description"></input>

Comment: @GordonBockus nope, but that would have been perfect

Comment: @kevin628 is a modal window that I am using to create an item and I want to use the same code to edit. When the user tap the 'new item' button, the modal window is appearing, and also when he tap the 'edit item' button

Comment: can you provide sample controller what you use? methinks you can try `<input ng-model="(newItem || item).description" />`

Comment: Why you cannot do smth like http://jsfiddle.net/z2Ly0co0/?

Comment: @Grundy I am using 2 different controllers. In the first doing this: `$scope.newItem = Items.getNewItem();` and in the second one: `$scope.item  = Items.getUserItemById($stateParams.itemId);`

Comment: so, do you try `input ng-model="(newItem || item).description" />` ?

Comment: @Grundy perfect! If you post this as an answer I would vote it. Thanks!

Comment: Please, avoid using of complex bindings, it is road to hell! :-) I'm sure you can do it in any case. Use $watch, directives and other instruments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

> ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope

so you can use expression for getting property what you need, something like this

```
<input ng-model="(newItem || item).description" />
```